# Disable input device auto switching from internal mic to external mic when I insert my head phones

Tags: xubuntu, microphone

I can't switch to internal mic when having my headphone inserted. I can't change my input device from external to internal. There is only one option in the drop-down when changes:

[image]

Comment: From the image, it seems you are using GNOME, but you set XUbuntu (XFCE) as a label

Comment: I am currently using the latest version of ubuntu

Comment: Please avoid *vague* terms like *latest*, if you're using Xubuntu 23.04 then please state so, instead of saying *latest* (*a number of users often only consider LTS releases for example, thus latest them them is actually three releases ago!*)   Please also add additional details to your question, which clearly states you're using Xubuntu currently (though image shows what maybe GNOME which is somewhat confusing).

Answer (score 0):

First unplug your headphones and make sure your internal microphone is  recording (`RUNNING` status). Open the Settings > Sound panel and activate it.

Then get the name of your internal microphone. Open a terminal and run the following:

```
pactl list short sources | grep input | grep RUNNING
```

For example, I have:

```
6   alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__hw_sofhdadsp_6__source   module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 48000Hz   RUNNING
```

So I should copy the name:

```
alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__hw_sofhdadsp_6__source
```

Then just [create a startup script](https://transang.me/three-ways-to-create-a-startup-script-in-ubuntu/) with an infinite loop so it forces the good input as followed :

```
while true; do 
    pactl set-default-source alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__hw_sofhdadsp_6__source
    sleep 0.5
done
```

Comment: Thanks man, I wish I had gotten this earlier