# Why can't I use my internal mic with headphones in Ubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, input-devices

My input device automatically changes to external mic when I plug in my headset. How do I force set my input to internal with my headset plugged in?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: possible duplicate of [your other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1479436/disable-input-device-auto-switching-from-internal-mic-to-external-mic-when-i-ins)